# How can Blood Potency 0 creatures heal Aggravated Damage?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

In [*Night Horrors: The Wicked Dead*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1588463745), there is the description of Blood Potency 0 effects. Quoting one of the items on page 11:

> Creatures with Blood Potency 0 can spend 1 vitae per turn, and can augment Physical Attributes and heal bashing and lethal damage as true Kindred can.

In there, I see no description of aggravated damage healing. Almost the same text describes the effect of the Blood Potency 0 for a Larva (p103). Again, no mention of aggravated damage.

So I must conclude the Blood Potency 0 creatures are simply unable to heal aggravated damage, but as I saw it clearly written nowhere, I guess I could use some advice.

The question: **Blood Potency 0 creatures** (Larva, and other "weak/half/whatever vampires") **should or shouldn't be able to heal aggravated damage?**

And if they can, **Is this process harder than for true vampires?** (what alternate rules would you then propose?)

Comment: Can I haz retitle? My first thought was "Yeah, what about them?"

Answer (score 5):

I believe this should be fairly simple. If the creature with `Blood Potency` is alive, then it should be allowed to heal using both natural ways (for humanlike creatures you should use mortal healing times) and `Vitae`. If the creature is dead, then it should only be allowed to heal using Vitae (so, spending 5 `Vitae` during 2 days it should be able to heal `Aggravated` damage).

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of a full rules clarification from White Wolf (try their forums), you could always use the rules for mortals and aggravated damage (p 175 World of Darkness rule book: One point is regained in a week).

Comment: The problem is that vampires/undead are not supposed to heal *at all* without spending vitae.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify the question then. Because you suggested that they could be half-vampires (ie partly alive). Failing that I think gruszczy has given a suitable answer. Really, common sense prevails. What ever works for you in your world setting. Remember the golden rule, "change the rules if they don't work for you."